# Input matches no features in training set; how much more training data do I need?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, classification

I am new to Text Mining. I am working on Spam filter. I did text cleaning, removed stop words. n-grams are my features. So I build a frequency matrix and build model using Naive Bayes.  I have very limited set of training data, so I am facing the following problem.

When a sentence comes to me for classification and if none of its features match with the existing features in training then my frequency vector has only zeros.

When I send this vector for classification, I obviously get a useless result.

What can be ideal size of training data to expect better results?

Comment: It's not hard to obtain more spam.

Comment: Obtaining more spam is not difficult but obtaining relevant posts is dfficult. I am working on webform posts. Can I know the ideal size of training data

Comment: Then your features aren't rich enough. Manually or by ontology create categories for related words, e.g. 'advance fee', 'funds', 'bank transfer', 'Western Union', 'money order', 'draft', 'lottery', 'prize', 'winnings', etc. Do that for all your spam categories (e.g. pharmaceuticals, work-from-home, etc.). Then rerun and recheck anything which still matches no features. Post us several examples here to make things reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the more data you have, the better. You will get diminishing returns at some point. It is often a good idea to see if your training set size is a problem by plotting the cross validation performance while varying the size of the training set. In scikit-learn has an example of this type of "[learning curve](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_learning_curve.html)."

**Scikit-learn Learning Curve Example**

[image: Scikit-learn learning curve]

You may consider bringing in outside sample posts to increase the size of your training set.

As you grow your training set, you may want to try reducing the bias of your classifier. This could be done by adding n-gram features, or switching to a logistic regression or SVM model.

Answer (score 0):

> When a sentence comes to me for classification and if none of its features match with the existing features in training then my frequency vector has only zeros.

You should normalize your input so that it forms some kind of rough distribution around 0. A common method is to do this tranformation:

```
input_signal = (feature - feature_mean) / feature_stddev
```

Then all zeroes would only happen if all features were exactly at the mean.

Comment: How does that help resolve the issue when the features are all exactly at the mean, which is what I expect would happen then?  If you don't have any information about any of the extracted features, they continue to fail to enable you to make any decision.

Comment: It would be extremely hard for a text to have all features end up at exactly the mean. It would typically mean that the text has to contain the word "V1GRA" 0.00434211111 times and the word "PRINCE" 0.0003213232 times. But there is a solution to that as well, which is to insert a dummy value 1 in all samples that can then control what happens if all the other features are 0.

Comment: The fundamental problem with an extremely sparse feature model is precisely that it is quite likely that none of the input features occurred in the training data. Again, manipulating the calculations you do with known features can't help for unknown features.

Comment: If a feature isn't present anywhere in the training data I guess it will be hard to calculate a global mean and stddev, and those can change over time as well. I do not know of a way to handle that.